# blog site allowing to paste images from clipboard

Tags: blogs, web

I tried blogger.com - it does not support such an obvious thingL copy-paste an image from my computer into the new blog post I'm editing. Is there any blogger site, which would support this?

Comment: This is a programming Q&A website. Your question doesn't belong here unless you're asking on how to implement such a feature?

Comment: oops. which site would you recommend then? I like stackoverflow and I always see tons of good responses here, so I decided to post here

Comment: maybe http://webapps.stackexchange.com but I'm not sure if it's *on topic* there. Read their [FAQ](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq#questions).

Answer (score 5):

Once alternative is to set up Blogger to post from email. That way, you can use GMail or any other email clients where you can paste the image from clipboard.

For more information on how to set it up on Blogger, please refer to [Post via email](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/41452?hl=en)

This is the most common way I update my blogs, with the added benefit of the content archived via GMail, and easily re-shared.

[image: Screenshot of updating Blogger via GMail]

Comment: thanks for the advice. I've tried that and works like a charm